# Distinct user in cassandra , how to do that?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra-2.0

I working on an big data application in scala.

I use kafka, spark (with kafka streaming) and Cassandra as storage.

I have an application outside of spark which request Cassandra to show statistics result like number of download.

I have a problemat with the user statistics.

I need to count the number of unique users in a period (could be 1 day ,6 days  7 days, one month or whatever) by publisher_id , or by publisher_id + app_id or even for all publisher_id.

I need to count in live because I don t know what is the period chosen by the user.

My raw data for session user is :

```
CREATE TABLE tests2.raw_sessions (
date_event timeuuid,
    year int,
    month int,
    day int,
    hour int,
    publisher_id uuid,
    app_id text,
    user_id text,
     session_id text,
     PRIMARY KEY (date_event, year, month, day, hour, publisher_id, app_id, 
     user_id, session_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (year DESC, month DESC, day DESC, hour DESC, publisher_id ASC, app_id ASC, user_id ASC, session_id ASC)
```

I created multiple tables and tried a lot of things in cassandra. I tried to use the distinct keyword in cassandra but it s only with static column (but it s not static column ) and it can be a unique partition key in a table (i need to filter on the date , and the publisher id , app_id

I thought about using a Postgres database but with kafka streaming this is not really optimal isn't it?

What is THE solution I should use for that?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to query Cassandra or Spark ?

Comment: I want to query Cassandra.
And get the Uniq users list for a period with a filter by publisher_id.
i don t know how to do that with Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

With cassandra data modeling, data copy is very helpful. Cassandra is write intensive databse. Writes are very cheap. While modeling data, always think of what single query.

```
 Uniq users list for a period by publisher_id
```

If you see, you have requirement of three quesries.

```
1. Unique users by publisher id for a perieod of day.
2. Unique users by publisher id for a perieod of month.
3. Unique users by publisher id for a perieod of year.
```

Better way is to create three different tables

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_year(
year int,
month int,
day int,
hour int,
publisher_id uuid,
app_id text,
user_id text,
session_id text,
PRIMARY KEY ((year,publisher_id),user_id )
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(user_id  DESC)

CREATE TABLE users_by_month(
year int,
month int,
day int,
hour int,
timestamp int,
publisher_id uuid,
app_id text,
user_id text,
session_id text,
PRIMARY KEY ((month ,publisher_id),user_id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY( user_id DESC);

CREATE TABLE users_by_day(
year int,
month int,
day int,
hour int,
timestamp int,
publisher_id uuid,
app_id text,
user_id text,
session_id text,
PRIMARY KEY ((day,publisher_id),user_id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY( user_id DESC);
```

Thease model will keep unique uses for a publisher id for year, month,day.

```
Uniq users filetr by publisher_id

CREATE TABLE users_by_publisherid(
year int,
month int,
day int,
hour int,
timestamp int,
publisher_id uuid,
app_id text,
user_id text,
session_id text,
PRIMARY KEY (publisher_id,user_id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY( user_id DESC);
```

This table will keep unique users for publisher_id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gunwant. 
But i think it s incorrect, indeed , for user_by_day, 
If on the 1st of january a user come , a row will be written , then if on the 1st of february, the same user come again , it will rewrite the row isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Are the requirements that you absolutely must have super accurate data on the counts. If not using an estimation data structure like HyperLogLog can help immensely.